# SEFAZ - NFeDistribuicaoDFe - c# - Console Application

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

Desde já informo que não entendo muito de SOAP nem XML e eu só estou postando a pergunta antes de estudar bastante, pois estou com um prazo muito apertado.

Estou precisando fazer um consulta na SEFAZ no *webservice* [NFeDistribuicaoDFe](https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx).

Ao abrir as classes achei bem confuso então adicionei um `?WSDL` no final e o *webservice* me retorno apenas com a classe `NFeDistribuicaoDFe`.

Dentro dessa classe eu pude notar que ela espera receber um `XmlNode`. Código do *webservice*:

```
        /// <remarks/>
    public event nfeDistDFeInteresseCompletedEventHandler nfeDistDFeInteresseCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/nfeDistDFeInteresse", RequestNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe", ResponseNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public System.Xml.XmlNode nfeDistDFeInteresse(System.Xml.XmlNode nfeDadosMsg) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("nfeDistDFeInteresse", new object[] {
                    nfeDadosMsg});
        return ((System.Xml.XmlNode)(results[0]));
    }
```

Pelo que eu entendi *XmlNode* é um nó do XML o que já achei estranho, pois esperava enviar o XML completo e não só o nó dele, segue o código que eu fiz tentando consumir esse *webservice*:

```
        try
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                         "<distDFeInt versao=\"1.00\" xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\">" +      
                         "<tpAmb>1</tpAmb>" +       
                         "<cUFAutor>35</cUFAutor>" +       
                         "<CNPJ>99999999999999</CNPJ>" +      
                         "<distNSU>" +      
                         "<ultNSU>0</ultNSU>" +
                         "</distNSU>" +
                         "</distDFeInt>";

            XmlNode xmlNodeRequest, xmlNodeResponse;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            xmlNodeRequest = doc.FirstChild;

            ServiceNFe.NFeDistribuicaoDFe nFeDistribuicao = new ServiceNFe.NFeDistribuicaoDFe();
            xmlNodeResponse = nFeDistribuicao.nfeDistDFeInteresse(xmlNodeRequest);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro: " + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

**Observação:**: o ServiceNFe foi criado aqui:

[image: Serviço de Referência WEB]

Esse é o erro que da ao tentar executar:

[image: Catch]

Informações do meu `xmlNodeRequest` (Só está pegando a primeira linha, como já esperava):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

To perdido, como eu envio o XML completo? esse código está certo?

Comment: e qual é a dúvida ? acesse o [tour] pra saber como perguntar

Comment: Esqueci de colocar o erro Rovann, vou inserir, mas pra adiantar isso não funciona o meu XmlNode pega apenas a primeira linha do XML e ao fazer o envio meu ctch informa que não foi possível criar o XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom pessoal, consegui fazer funcionar na unha, vou deixar minha solução aqui para caso mais alguém passe por esse problema:

```
#region Certificado

            var objCertificadoX509 = new X509Certificate2([CAMINHODO CERTIFICADO], [SENHA]); //Pegando dados do Certificado

            #endregion

            #region XML

            //Instancia
            XmlNode Noderequest, Noderesponse;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            NFeDistribuicaoDFe distribuicaoDFe = new NFeDistribuicaoDFe();
            string NSU, base64, xmlNota;

            //Criação da String XML
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                         "<distDFeInt versao=\"1.00\" xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\">" +
                         "<tpAmb>1</tpAmb>" +
                         "<cUFAutor>35</cUFAutor>" +
                         "<CNPJ>[CNPJ]</CNPJ>" +
                         "<distNSU>" +
                         "<ultNSU>000000000000000</ultNSU>" +
                         "</distNSU>" +
                         "</distDFeInt>";



            //Convertendo a string em xml
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            //Transformando o XML em XmlNode (Requisito da API)
            Noderequest = doc.DocumentElement;

            #endregion

            #region Envio API

            //Setando os Atributos de Certificado e endereço de envio
            distribuicaoDFe.ClientCertificates.Add(objCertificadoX509);
            distribuicaoDFe.Url = "https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx?wsdl";

            //Envio ao WebService
            Noderesponse = distribuicaoDFe.nfeDistDFeInteresse(Noderequest);

            #endregion

            #region Tratamento
            Noderesponse = Noderequest.FirstChild.LastChild;

            //Percorre todos os Nós do XML principal
            foreach (XmlNode loopNode in Noderesponse)
            {
                NSU = loopNode.Attributes["NSU"].Value;
                base64 = loopNode.InnerText;

                //Descompactar a nota
                byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
                xmlNota = Decompress(buffer);

                //Carregar xml descompactado
                doc.LoadXml(xmlNota);

                //Pegando os valores do XML compactado
                XmlNode globalNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("resNFe");
                XmlNode pathImpNode = globalNode.SelectSingleNode("chNFe");
                string chave = pathImpNode.InnerText;
            }

            #endregion
```

E esse aqui é o código que eu achei na internet para descompactar o DocZip do xml de retorno da SEFAZ, que está sendo usando ali dentro do FOREACH

```
 static string  Decompress(byte[] gzip)
    {
        using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new
        MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            const int size = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.ToArray());

            }
        }
    }
```

Só lembrando também que isso é um ConsoleApplication, ou seja, eu só montei o básico do básico, só pra ver funcionar, quem for utilizar não se esqueça de criar as validações try catch e etc... e ali em certificado usar metodos para pegar informações de certificados instalados, não é uma boa pratica deixar o caminho e a senha no HARDCODE...

Answer (score 0):

Pra mim, o código que funcionou para descompactar o gzip é:

```
private static string GzipDecodeWW(string inputStr)
{
    byte[] inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputStr);

    using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(inputBytes))
    using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        gZipStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
        var outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray();

        string decompressed = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBytes);

        return decompressed;
    }
}
```